# Kali Linux Veil-Evasion install problem

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I can't install Veil-Evasion. I have this error:

> Installing (Wine) i386 Binaries
>   Reading package lists...
>   Building dependency tree...
>   Reading state information...
>   Package wine-bin:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>   E: Package 'wine-bin:i386' has no installation candidate
>    [ERROR] Failed To Install Wine... Exit Code: 0.

Comment: You are asking all these questions on the wrong forum. We are not Kali tech support.

Answer (score 1):

You can add WineHQ repository and download it from console. Kali-Linux is Debian based, Ubuntu also, so you can try with ubuntu's repository, or just search debian one.
type in console

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
apt-get update
```

after that type

```
apt-get install -f
```

This should install missing packages for the program. If it doesn't help, download it manually.